# Loop over subsets of data in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
value <- c(2,3,3,4,2,2,4,4,3,2,2,3)
df <- data.frame(id, value)
```

What i would like to do now is compile two data-frames of the first ids (1 and 2) and compile a calculation on it. The I want to move on the next two data-frames (with id 3 and 4) and perform a calculation on it etc...And this for all rows. So the psuedo code looks like:

```
#loop over dataframe
 for i in 1:nrow(df) {

  #fetch the rows of the first two ids
  #perform calculcation on ti
  #move on to the next two columns
  #perform calculation on it.

}
```

Any clues on how I can code this most effecient in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R solution. The groups were built using a binning approach. Odd factor levels will be set to NA.

```
gr <- .bincode(df$id,seq(0,max(df$id),2))
aggregate(df$value,list(gr),mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making an explicit `id_pair` variable that groups the values for `id` as you describe. Then you can perform your computation grouped on the new `id_pair` variable. Here is an example using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id_pair = ceiling(id / 2)) %>%
  group_by(id_pair) %>%
  summarise(
    ids = paste(unique(id), collapse = ", ")
    mean_value = mean(value)
    )


Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

  id_pair mean_value   ids
    (dbl)      (dbl) (chr)
1       1   2.666667  1, 2
2       2   3.000000  3, 4
```

You can also get the result without storing `id_pair` as an intermediate value:

```
df %>%
  group_by( ceiling(id / 2)) %>%
  summarise(mean_value = mean(value))

Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  ceiling(id/2) mean_value
          (dbl)      (dbl)
1             1   2.666667
2             2   3.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways to do this, but here's one I came up with. First, create a list of the id's you'd like to subset by, then use those list entries in a `subset` function within an `aggregate` function.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
value <- c(2,3,3,4,2,2,4,4,3,2,2,3)
df <- data.frame(id, value)
df_list = list(c(1,2), c(3,4))
#not grouped by id
for(i in 1:2){
 sum_df =  aggregate(value~1, FUN = function(x) c('sd' = sd(x),
                                                  'mean' = mean(x)),
                     data = subset(df, id %in% df_list[[i]]))
 assign(paste0('df',paste0(df_list[[i]], collapse = '')),
        sum_df)
}

> df12
   value.sd value.mean
1 0.8164966  2.6666667
> df34
   value.sd value.mean
1 0.8944272  3.0000000
#grouped by id
for(i in 1:2){
  sum_df =  aggregate(value~id, FUN = function(x) c('sd' = sd(x),
                                                   'mean' = mean(x)),
                      data = subset(df, id %in% df_list[[i]]))
  assign(paste0('dfg',paste0(df_list[[i]], collapse = '')),
         sum_df)
}
> dfg12
  id  value.sd value.mean
1  1 0.5773503  2.6666667
2  2 1.1547005  2.6666667
> dfg34
  id  value.sd value.mean
1  3 0.5773503  3.6666667
2  4 0.5773503  2.3333333
```